Big 4 short, with character having jewels hidden in skin
Short story in one of the traditional SF digest-sized magazines. 1975-1985. I think pretty close to 1980. In Analog, FSF, Galaxy, or Amazing. More likely one of the first two. Definitely that size though (the Reader's Digest size).
I don't remember most of the plot. At one point, one of the characters produces some jewels out of a skin pocket of himself. Not like they grow there or he is an animal with a pouch. More like if one of us stuck jewels into a wound.
I think it was sort of a sword and sorcery motif, but not sure. I don't think it had to do with theft or fencing, but more like an ultra secure pouch. I kinda think the fellow was on the run.
However, for all of the above, I worry that I'm starting to conflate one old memory with a more recent one. In the blockbuster movie, The Egyptian, there is a scene towards the end where the hero sends his son off with a rogue, who has some jewels, he uses to buy their way onto an escape ship (from the anti-monotheists). But I think that was not from a skin pouch, and I remember thinking of the similarity on watching the movie, so separate stories.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  While this seems like a memorable detail, it would greatly help if you could remember more details.  Why did they need jewels?  Was it a fantasy world where they would be currency, or was it set in a contemporary setting where the character robbed a museum or a jeweler?  Did they fence the jewels, use them for bribes...

Adding.................
